# PHP write new file in apache localserver

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm having problems to create a new file from a parsed previous one.
I have this code in `javascript/jQuery` (a piece of it):

```
$('#button').live('click', function (e) {
        var file_name_srt_URL = 'folder_one/' + file_name_
        translatedLanguage = $('#input_text').val();
        var lang_from = shortLanguage(originalLanguage);//it's simple function, does something like: originalLanguage = english -> return 'en'
        var lang_to = shortLanguage(translatedLanguage);
        var jsonNameFile = JSON.stringify(file_name_srt_URL);
        var jsonLangFrom = JSON.stringify(lang_from);
        var jsonLangTo = JSON.stringify(lang_to);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "traduction.php",
            data: {data: jsonNameFile, langFrom: jsonLangFrom, langTo: jsonLangTo}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(){
                alert("Success!");
                hideMsgBox();
            }
        });
    });
```

And now, the `PHP` Code:

```
<?php
define('SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER', 0);
define('SRT_STATE_TIME',      1);
define('SRT_STATE_TEXT',      2);
define('SRT_STATE_BLANK',     3);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
function translate($text, $from, $to){
    //fake user-agent
    ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
    ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');//set encoding in case it's other than utf-8 (you might need to re-set it afterwords)
    $get_string = 'hl=' . $from . '&tl=' . $to . '&q=' . urlencode($text);
    $data = file_get_contents('http://translate.google.es/?' . $get_string);
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($data);
    $items = $DOM->getElementById('result_box');
    return $items->nodeValue;
}
$file_name = json_decode($_POST['data']); //original filename route 
$lang_from = json_decode($_POST['langFrom']); //original language
$lang_to = json_decode($_POST['langTo']); //final language to translate

$url_to = 'new/'; //directory to save the new file
$_file_srt = str_replace("folder_1/", "$url_to", $file_name); //substitution Old Directory for the New one
$saveToFile = str_replace("$lang_from","$lang_to",$_file_srt); //substitution old language for the new one on the extension file

$subs    = array();
$state   = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;
$subNum  = 0;
$subText = '';
$subTime = '';
$space = "\n";
$blank = " ";
$arrow = " --> ";

$lines   = file($file_name); //read file
foreach($lines as $line) {
    switch($state) {
        case SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER:
            $subNum = trim($line);
            $state  = SRT_STATE_TIME;
            break;

        case SRT_STATE_TIME:
            $subTime = trim($line);
            $state   = SRT_STATE_TEXT;
            break;

        case SRT_STATE_TEXT:
            if (trim($line) == '') {
                $sub = new stdClass;
                $sub->number = $subNum;
                list($sub->start, $sub->end) = explode(' --> ', $subTime);
                $sub->text   = $subText;
                $subText     = '';
                $state       = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;

                $subs[]      = $sub;
            } else {
                $subText .= $line;
            }
            break;
    }
}

if (isset($file_name))
{
    $h = fopen($saveToFile, 'w+');
    if ($h) {
        foreach ($subs as $sub) {
            fwrite($h,$sub->number);
            fwrite($h,$space);
            fwrite($h,$sub->start);
            fwrite($h,$arrow);
            fwrite($h,$sub->end);
            fwrite($h,$space);
            fwrite($h,$sub->text);
            fwrite($h,$space);
            fwrite($h,$space);
        }
        fclose($h);
    }
    exit('Data Saved.');
}
?>
```

My problem is no file is created at any directory, I don't know why, because I did this things before with other files, but now I can't find the problem! I'm trying to debug the PHP code through the browser console, with `http://www.codeforest.net/debugging-php-in-browsers-javascript-console` debug class code, but nothing appears in my console, I don't know what Can I do for running this...

Any one can help me? Please
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Finally it worked, thank you all!

Comment: Do you have permision to write to that folder?

Comment: Don't forget to use `is_writable` in order to make sure that you can write in this file.

Comment: Are you getting the 'data saved.' message? Are you getting any errors when attempting the write? Try exit(error_get_last());

Comment: @Legionar Yes, of course, I'm saving other kind of files inside these folders with PHP code (very close to the posted one) and everything works fine ...

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($save_to_file)` to see what filename/path you're generating? You have a LOT of assumptions in there that completely ignore the possibility of failure of bad/no data being passed in.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, of course I did this through Linux Console and everything seems to work... but I don't obtain the same results through the browser...

Comment: I just make another test, alone, runing the PHP code through Linux console again and everything worked good, parsed and tanslated my text, but I can't figured out what is happening when I try to run it through the browser...